# Calculate value with tolerance

Tags: c#

I have a input value e.g.

```
decimal input = 100.4m;
```

and a comparison value / a tolerance which can change. So in this example `99.5` to `100.5` are valid, other input values not.

```
decimal tolerance = 0.5m;
decimal compareValue = 100m;
```

question: is there a more elegant way to validate than this:

```
bool isValid = (input >= compareValue - tolerance) && (input <= compareValue + tolerance);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends how you define elegant...! You can use Abs to also do the check:

```
bool isValid = Math.Abs(input - compareValue) <= tolerance;
```

Comment: this is elegant - using every variable only once and easy to read / understand